# Convert Png to SVG programmatically in Offline environments

Tags: powershell, image, type-conversion

I am looking to Convert PNG to SVG.

The target system is offline so I can't call online services in the script.
I am looking to avoid installing third party services/software as well.
Portable versions can work if needed.

Windows system so please use CMD or Powershell.

I tried to use InkSpace Portanle 1.2.2 version but the portable version do not accept scripting (or atlest i could not make it work).

Current script:

```
param(
[string]$path = 'C:\Users\<user>\Downloads\Convert',
[string]$exec = "C:\Users\<user>\Downloads\InkscapePortable\InkscapePortable.exe")

foreach ($filename in Get-ChildItem $path) {
    if ($filename.toString().EndsWith('.png')) {        

    $targetName = $filename.BaseName + ".svg";

    #Write-Output -"Converting $filename ..."

    $command = "& `"$exec`" --export-type='svg' --export-filename='$targetName' $fileName"; 
    Invoke-Expression $command;        
}
}
```

I tried to use the script above with Portable version of InkSpace but it only loaded the exe without exporting the svg.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/110833/457871 as a start point

Comment: Thank you. I found the following using your suggestion. I will try to write a script and post it here for future reference.

https://github.com/visioncortex/vtracer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Digging I learned a lot about SVG.

I found that you can embed a photo as base64 in the SVG instead of trace the image and vector it.

This may be slower to process (as read in some places) but do not lower the image resolution as with some of the tools found.

In my case, embedding is an acceptable solution.

Below is my working script:

```
$File ='' #Image file path here such as D:\old.png
$Export='' ##Export Path such as D:\new.svg

$CompanyLogo=Get-Content -Path $file -AsByteStream
$CompanyLogo=[System.Convert]::ToBase64String($CompanyLogo)

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Drawing
$image = New-Object System.Drawing.Bitmap $File
$Width=$image.Width
$Height=$image.Height

$XML = "<?xml version=""1.0"" standalone=""no""?>
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC ""-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN""
    ""http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd"">
    <svg version=""1.0""   xmlns=""http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"" xmlns:xlink=""http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink""
    width=""$Width"" height=""$Height"" >
    <image
        width=""$Width"" height=""$Height""
        href=""data:image/png;base64,$CompanyLogo""
        />
    </svg>"

$XML | Out-File -FilePath $Export -Force
```